# city specific job search query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table

```
jobs
------------------------------------------
id  | title     | descrition     | city
------------------------------------------
01  | title 1   | description 1  | pune
02  | title 2   | des title 2    | agra
```

i want to search a job title and description from specific city, and i am using the below query to search but its get wrong result, please help me. i am new in sql

```
select * from jobs where title like '%title%'
or description like '%title%' and city='mohali'
```

result is wrong it shows both of the above results, where i need city specific, i dont want any result if city is not matched.

Comment: You need single quotes around all the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and` binds stronge than `or` which is called operator precedence. Use parentheses

```
select * from jobs 
where 
(
  title like '%title%'
  or description like '%title%'
)
and city = 'agra'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Gordon said, you need to use single quotes around all your strings. Also, you need to use parentheses to bind your `either or` scenario like this:

```
select * from jobs 
where 
(
  title like '%title%'
  or description like '%title%'
)
and city = 'agra';
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37ccb/1/0)